# Initialize an generic object in if-else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, generics, types

I need to create a generic object with type that depend on user choice. I get it from radio buttons. Here is an idea that I imagine:

```
        Class<null> object;

        if (radioInteger.Checked == true)
        {
            object = new Class<int>();
        }
        if (radioFloat.Checked == true)
        {
            object list = new Class<float>();
        }
        if (radioString.Checked == true)
        {
            object list = new Class<String>();
        }

        //do smth with object
```

How can I do it with C#?

I have tried to put type in variable and then put it between <>, but compiler says that I put variable instead of type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You've already provided an example of how to do what you want in C# havent you?

Comment: You need to introduce a common base type or interface which all `Class<T>` can be assigned to. eg `abstract class Class{} ... class Class<T>:Class{}`.

Comment: What is the `Class` class, exactly, and what does the generic argument do in it?

Comment: I'd give `Class<T>` a non generic interface or super class and work from there. The alternative is to use reflection, and that's a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type is not known at compile-time then you have to construct your object using the type object/instance and not a type argument/generic. Look into the non-generic overloads of `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Note that it is better if you can know the type at compile-time since then you could for example constrain it to types that have a default constructor. Otherwise, using the non-generic `Activator.CreateInstance` call, you may get an exception if there is no suitable constructor to call. This all depends on your particular design though.